# Passive FTP on Windows Server 2012 Using Filezilla Server Quits Working

Tags: ftp, passive

I've got a Filezilla FTP server running on Windows Server 2012 accepting passive transfers. The problem is that intermittently, the passive ftp quits working and giving 425- Connection Refused errors.

I've tried restarting the FTP service and restarting Filezilla but the only thing that I've found to fix it is to reboot the server. It will then work for anywhere from 1 - 4 days without a problem and then starts failing again.

I have Windows Firewall turned off so it's not an issue.

What else could I check?

Comment: It may be that another process is consuming all of the available I/O handles. What is your handles count under Process Manager?

Comment: From what I can see, the handle count is low. Filezilla Server only has 67 handles with the largest handle count going to dropbox with 1,463.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem.

I didn't have enough ports open in the AWS firewall. Once I gave Filezilla a greater range to work with and opened them up in my AWS security group the problem went away.